# Unable to create a null constant value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1'

Tags: c#, linq

Unable to create a null constant value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1'. Only entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported in this context."} System.SystemException {System.NotSupportedException}

I'm really confused on why this is not working. Both, query.ZipCodes has stuff in it, zipCodeDistribList has stuff in it, distribQuery has stuff in it. So I'm completely at a loss here.

```
if (query.States.Any())
{
    var statesDistribList =
        (from selectedState in query.States
         join distribStateXREF in LocationEntityProvider.Context.MD_DISTRB_ST_XREF
            on selectedState equals distribStateXREF.ST_CD
         select distribStateXREF.MD_DISTRB_NBR
         ) ?? new List<decimal>();

    if (statesDistribList.Any())
    {
        distribQuery = distribQuery.Where(distrib => statesDistribList.Contains(distrib.Number));
    }
    statesDistribList = null;
}
```

query.States is an IEnumerable
distribQuery is an IEnumerable
statesDistribList *see above code*

The error happens on distribQuery, which has stuff from an earlier query; so I know that nulls really can't be the underlying issue here.

Comment: LINQ query never returns `null`, so using it with `??` seems like not a really good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
statesDistribList = null
```

Your query is only being executed after this line.
Therefore, it is null.

Comment: @Selman22: So? The problem comes when the subsequent `Where()` query is enumerated.

Comment: Ah you're right! Thanks for that! Plus found out the error came from a sub query that had a DefaultIfEmpty(), after I removed it, things started to work.